# Determining points on a n-spiral

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I'm trying to generate points on a n-dimensional helix. I'm using a fix angle and maintaining the radius equals to 1.
Is there a formula/pattern to determine the points in more than 3 dimensions?

Regards.

Comment: using a fixed angle of helix maintaining cylinder radius $=1$